# Do you need to be both level 20 and have the expansion pack 2 to unlock The Reef social place?

Tags: destiny

I completed the campaign yesterday and tried to access the reef but it said that I have to help the queen hunt down her enemies .

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the *House of Wolves* expansion pack (the second one), and have reached level 20.  Until you have completed the final mission, *The Black Garden*, The Reef campaign will be unavailable.

You can access The Reef as a social space without the expansion, but you still need to be level 20.  You won't really be able to do anything there either until you buy the expansions, although sometimes Xûr shows up there now instead of in The Tower.

Comment: Wait, my mistake, you don't need the expansion to access the social area alone, you just won't be able to do much there without *House of Wolves*.

Comment: I don't think you need to finish The Black Garden in order to start the House of Wolves missions. I haven't finished The Black Garden yet on my hunter, and Petra will give me the bounty for the first House of Wolves mission.

Comment: @Adeese is correct, you do not need to have completed the main campaign to access the reef quest line, you only need to be level 20.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to be lvl 20 and have HoW (House of Wolves DLC2) to access the reef social space.

I hope this helped. Good luck Guardian.